# Is length contraction, physical or temporal in nature?

Tags: special-relativity, relativity

If I travel from A to B, the trip gets shorter, the faster I travel. Not distance shorter, but rather, time/duration shorter. Now, due to time dilation, any distance I travel, would become "duration contracted", the greater my speed.

For example, at 99% of light speed, only 1.42 years pass on my clock, for every 10 years that pass on earth. 10 light years is time contracted to 1.42 years, in my reference frame.

The physical distance doesn't change.

Comment: *Not distance shorter, but rather, time/duration shorter.* Distances, as well as durations, become shorter.

Comment: @MohammadJavanshiry that is the current, incorrect, interpretation. There is no physical change in distance, in my opinion. It's purely temporal.

Comment: Imagine you set off a nova. Then you travel to another star and set off another nova. Everybody for a long distance can see both novas. But when they travel at different velocities, they might measure the distance between the novas and the times they happen to be different. Of course there were only two novas and they don't change when people measure them different. But the claim is that the measurements are in fact different.

Answer (score 2):

### A stick on the Cartesian plane

I have a stick. It's 5 units long, and it is currently positioned such that it's ends are 4 units apart in the x-direction and 3 units apart in the y-direction.

I also have this goofy friend who uses a set of axes twisted with respect to mine. He insists that they stick is 3 units in the x-direction and 4-units in the y-direction.

> Is the difference we measure in the x-length of the stick due to x or due to y?

The correct answer is of course, "Neither. It is down to the difference in the coordinate systems you've chosen."

### Distance in Cartesian and Minkowski space.

The distance between two points on the Cartesian plane is 
$$ d = \sqrt{ (\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta y)^2 } \;, \tag{Cartesian distance}$$
and the interesting thing about the stick is that we agree on the distance between the ends even though we disagree on the x-length and the y-length. Distances in Cartesian space are invariant under rotations of the coordiate system.

Space-time in relativity is a Minkowski space, the generalization of distance in a 1+1-dimensional Minkowski space is defined (using $c=1$ units) as<sup>1</sup>
$$ s = \sqrt{(\Delta t)^2 - (\Delta x)^2} \;. \tag{Minkowski distance}$$
Distances in Minkoski space are invariant under certain transformations too. Those transformation include spacial rotations (when we are using more than one spacial dimension), but *also* include "boosts". In relativity a "boost" is exactly the difference between the points of view of observers moving relative one another.

#### A digression on signs

With the stick example, my friend sees the stick longer in the y-direction and shorter in the x-direction. Because distance in invariant and the plus-sign in the disance formula if one direction grows the other must decrease.

The Minkowski distance has a minus sign, so if one direction decreases the other direction must *also* decrease. That is what happens in relativity.<sup>2</sup>

### Answer to the question.

The answer to the title question is **"Neither. It's an effect of chosing different sets of axes in Minkowski geometry"**

You're trying to assign deep phiolosophical meaning to the projections of a segment onto coordinate axes and getting surprised when observer using different sets of axes get differnt answers. But all you are observing is that they are using different coordinate systems.

It is no more mysterous than the stick example, though wrapping your head around the relationship between boosts and Minkoski rotations takes a little doing.

---

<sup>1</sup> Some authors flip the order of the terms in the square-root. This changes a lot of sign conventions but does not affect the basic argument. I'm using the convention prefered in particle physics.

<sup>2</sup> Dont be confused by the names "time dilation" and "length contraction"; they may sound like they imply opposite sign changes, but that's just confusing use of language. The constancy of the speed of light means that if the distance gets shorter the elapsed time must also get shorter, and it does.

Comment: I fully agree with you that if the distance gets shorter, the elapsed time must also get shorter. That doesn't mean if the elapsed time gets shorter, the distance must necessarily get shorter.

Comment: @Zane $s$ is a Lorentz invariant. It doesn't change any more than the length of the stick changes when my freind and I measure it with different coordinate systems. So yeah, if the elapsed time gets shorts the distance *must* get shorter as well. The two are intimately coupled by the invariant nature of $s$.

Comment: I fully agree, but it's not the physical length of the distance which changes. It's the time taken to travel that distance, which changes. If you travel from A to B and accelerate, the trip gets shorter. Not distance shorter. Duration shorter. Length contraction is temporal in nature. Not spatial. The relative aspect of space-time, is time, not space.

Answer (score 1):

You must define what distance is in order to identify whether it is changing. In special relativity the distance between two points is measured by holding up a ruler between both points such that the ends of the ruler simultaneously align with each object. To make this more physical, imagine measuring length as two events that happen at the same time: one event is when the first object comes in contact with the ruler, making a mark on the ruler. The second object does the same, leaving a mark. You then subtract the measurements corresponding to the marks on the ruler. You define this to be the length of the object, in the reference frame of the person who saw the events to be simultaneous.

Using this definition of distance, moving objects do indeed have their lengths contracted, because simultaneity is different between moving observers.

In your example, you are thinking of Earth frame measurements as being the “more real” measurements, which is why you are arriving to the conclusion that time dilation is more real than length contraction: in the Earth frame, the distance you travel is not length contracted, but there is a disagreement in the duration of the trip between you and the Earth frame. However, in your frame, you would indeed measure the distance to be length contracted. As another example, imagine the entire Earth was traveling through a galaxy at 0.99c. We would indeed measure the galaxy to be length contracted! If you accept the above definition of distance, then length contraction is real and physical.

Comment: No, that's not how distances are measured in relativity. We don't have rulers that long. We measure how long it takes light to travel that distance and divide that by the speed of light.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that you travel from the Earth to Xebulon, a planet that is 9.9 light-years away.  You hop in your super-rocket and travel to Xebulon at 99% of the speed of light, relative to the Earth.  According to clocks on Earth, this takes 10 years.  According to clocks on your ship, it takes 1.41 years.  This much we are in agreement on.

The two questions that arise are:

1. While you're traveling, how far apart do you observe Earth and Xebulon to be?
2. While you're traveling, how fast do you observe Earth and Xebulon (and other stars at rest relative to them) to be moving, relative to you?

You seem to be saying that the answer to question 1 is also "9.9 light-years".  But we would also expect that Earth and Xebulon are moving relative to us at $0.99c$ in the direction opposite our motion.  This would imply that Earth and Xebulon, 9.9 light-years apart, travel past us at $v = 0.99 c$;  and this should take $\Delta t = \Delta x/v = 10$ years.  This contradicts the assertion that the time elapsed on my clock should only be 1.41 years when I arrive at Xebulon.

This means that one of our assumptions must be false;  they were:

- The time elapsed on the rocket's clock is 1.41 years when it arrives.
- The rocket observes Earth and Xebulon to be moving with a speed of $0.99 c$.
- The distance between Earth and Xebulon, as observed from the rocket, is 10 light-years.

The standard interpretation is that the third assumption is the faulty one.  It might be possible to drop one of the other two assumptions and still have a self-consistent model;  in particular, the second and third assumptions are true in regular old Newtonian physics, while the first one is faulty.  However, many experiments have been performed showing that moving clocks really do "run slow", most famously [Frisch and Smith's muon-decay experiment.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbzt8gDSYIM)

Comment: While you are traveling, you observe the Earth and Xebulon to be 9.9*9.6*10^15m apart. According to your clock, it takes light 1.42 years to travel from one to the other. Space-time contracts, not space.

Comment: @zanescheepers:  So is your contention that on the rocket ship, you see Earth and Xebulon to travel past you at $(9.9 \text{ light-years})/(1.41 \text{ years}) \approx 7c$?

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Answer (score -1):

Time is never contracted, it may only be dilated (by time dilation).

You have to distinguish the proper time of the clock of the spaceship which is the time before time dilation (1,42 years) and the coordinate time of an observer which is the time after time dilation (10 years).

However, from the point of view of the spaceship, time is running normally: The clock is ticking normally, the heart of the astronauts is beating normally, and at their arrival, they really did not age by 10 years but only by 1,42 years.

If the astronauts are asking at their arrival: How did we manage to travel 10 light years in only 1,42 years?, their answer can  n o t   be time dilation, because time was running normally from their point of view. And this is exactly the point where space contraction is needed.

That means, people on Earth (the observing frame) will explain the low age of the astronauts with time dilation, and the astronauts (the frame whose movement is observed) can only explain it with space contraction.

Therefore, space contraction is only perceived by an observer who is moving near speed of light. That means, when the astronauts are arriving, they do not perceive length contraction any more, but the effect of their anterior travel is real: they aged only by 1,42 years.

By the way, this consequence seems to imply a frame of a preferred observer (and there is no unanimous opinion on this issue), because: Who will tell us that the astronauts are moving near light speed, and that it is not Earth and the exoplanet which are moving near light speed in the opposite direction? So, with respect to what the astronaut must move near light speed? (This problem does exist for length contraction, but not for time dilation)

Comment: Time dilation doesn't only affect clocks. It also affects our biological clocks. Just because we don't experience time dilation, doesn't mean our clocks aren't ticking slower. As a traveller, I understand that the journey took me 10 years, but I only experienced 1.42 years. I certainly don't assume that my destination magically moved closer. That's a ridiculous assumption.

Comment: There is no such thing as "time contraction". Starting point is always the proper time of an observed object/ particle. This proper time is perceived by observers as dilated - time dilation. It is the principle of the twin paradox where the traveling twin is aging less than the twin who stayed home.